# StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-strictmode

Sometimes I get this SctrictMode Exception:

```java
2019-01-28 14:18:23.073 4597-4615/my.app.package E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:223)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:106)
        at okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:62)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:103)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at my.app.package.api.network.SetJsonContentTypeHeaderInterceptor.intercept(SetJsonContentTypeHeaderInterceptor.kt:15)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The only part of the mentioned in the exception code that belong to my app is `SetJsonContentTypeHeaderInterceptor`:

```java
import okhttp3.Interceptor

internal class SetJsonContentTypeHeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain) =
        chain.request()
            .let {
                it.newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .build()
            }
            .let { chain.proceed(it) }!!

}
```

The libraries versions used in the app:

okHttp: 3.11.0

retrofit: 2.4.0

What is a cause of it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of `BridgeInterceptor`, it clearly creates a `GzipSource` and doesn't close it. `GzipSource` implements `Source` which extends `Closeable`. It's not clear to me that this actually leaks any resources. Regardless, if you're seeing the strictmode violation it means the problem was cleaned up in the finalizer.

This was okhttp 3.12.1 and okio 1.15.0. There are much newer versions so this may be fixed.